# Make stream builder on firebase authchange wait for uploading user data when signup Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Hi everyone I want streambuilder waiting when user signup and uploading his data to firebase firestore, because when i fetch user's data after sign up to show it to the user it throw an exception because data didn't completely upload.

**code in main file home:**

```
 StreamBuilder<User?>( 
stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
 builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) { 
    if (snapshot.hasData) 
    { 
    return const HomeScreen();
    } else
     { 
    return const LoginSignupScreen(); 
    } 
    }, 
    ),
```

**code in signup file**

```
try { 
        userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
     email: userInfo.userEmail!, 
    password: userInfo.userPassword!);
                 final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance .ref() .child("userImages") .child('${userCredential.user!.uid}.jpg'); 
                await storageRef.putFile(userInfo.userImage!); userInfo.userImageUrl = await storageRef.getDownloadURL(); 
                currentUid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
                    // upload user info to database 
            await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Users").doc(currentUid).set({ "userName": userInfo.userName, 
            "userEmail": userInfo.userEmail, 
            "userWorkZone": userInfo.userWorkZone,
             "userImageUrl": userInfo.userImageUrl,
             "userAuth": userInfo.userAuth, 
            "userPhone": userInfo.userPhone, 
            "userRegestrationDate": userInfo.dateTime,
             "userAccountType": userInfo.userAccountType,
             "userJob": userInfo.userJob, });
```

**code to fetch data**

```
child: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>( stream: usersCollection.doc(user.uid).snapshots(),
builder: (context, streamSnapshot) 
{ 
if (streamSnapshot.hasData)
 { 
return CircleAvatar( 
backgroundImage: NetworkImage( streamSnapshot.data!["userImageUrl"]), ); 
}
```

[Streambuilder on main file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opyK4.jpg)

[Signup&upload user data method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtTmJ.jpg)

[Fetching user data when navigation to home page after signup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdNsT.jpg)

Provided on photo above

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of an image.

Comment: Please add the code to the question using the Edit button.